# how to send data from a php page to ajax page

Tags: javascript, php, sql, ajax

i have this code, now i want to send this $_SESSION['roll_id'] variable to another page menu.php where ajax function is written. how i send this variable to another ajax page for set data.

this is login.php page.

```
if($row["Login_Id"]==$username and $row["Login_Pass"]==$password)
{
echo "<h2 align='center'>" ."Login Sucessfull welcome" ." " .$row["Login_Id"] 
."</h2>" ;
$_SESSION['roll_id']=$row['Roll_Id'];
//echo "ID" .$_SESSION['roll_id']; (give roll id)
header("Location: menu.php");
}
else
{
    echo "<h2 align='center'>" ."Login Failed" ."</h2>";
}
```

this is menu.php page where whole functionality is written. i want to send rollid from this page to submenu.php where i can use this roll id in sql query.

```
<?php 
session_start();
$session = $_SESSION['roll_id'];
?>
<html>
<head>
<link href="menu_style.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script 
src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js">
</script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){

var rollid = '<?php json_encode($session); ?>';
$.ajax
({
    type:'post',
    url:'submenu.php',
    data:{"roll_id":rollid},
    success:function(response)
    {
        //console.log(response);
        var menuArray= JSON.parse(response);
        var html =""; 
        $.each( menuArray, function( key, value )
        {
            html += "<li><a href=''>" + value.Menu_Name + "</a>";   
            if(value.subMenu.length > 0)
            {

                console.log(JSON.stringify(value.subMenu));
                html += "<ul>";
                $.each( value.subMenu, function( key, subValue )
                {
                html += "<li><a href=''>" + subValue.text + "</a></li>";     
                });
                html += "</ul>";

            }  

            html += "</li>";
        });
        console.log(html);
        if(response!="")
        {
            $("#main_menu").html(html);
        }
    }
});
```

});

this is submenu.php page

```
<?php 
 session_start();
 include('config.php');
 $roll_id = $_POST['roll_id'];

 $q="select a.Roll_Id, a.Menu_Id, b.Menu_Name, b.Menu_URL,b.Menu_Level, 
 b.MainMenu_ID, b.Menu_Order, b.Account_id,b.is_deleted from roll_menu AS a 
 join menu AS b on a.Menu_Id=b.Menu_Id and a.Roll_Id=".$roll_id;
 $menu = mysqli_query($conn, $q);
 $mainMenu = array(); 
 foreach($menu as $x=>$value)
 {
  if($value['MainMenu_ID']==0)
  $mainMenu[]=$value;
 }
 $menuData= array();
 foreach($mainMenu as $y=>$value1)
 {  
 $subMenu= array();
 $m=$mainMenu[$y]['Menu_Id'];
 $q1="select a.Roll_Id, a.Menu_Id, b.Menu_Name, b.Menu_URL,
    b.Menu_Level, b.MainMenu_ID, b.Menu_Order, b.Account_id, 
    b.is_deleted from roll_menu AS a join menu AS b on
    a.Menu_Id=b.Menu_Id and a.Roll_Id=".$roll_id."and b.MainMenu_ID=$m"; 
 $menu1 = mysqli_query($conn, $q1);
 while($row=mysqli_fetch_array($menu1))
 {
    if($row["MainMenu_ID"]==$m)
    {
        $subMenu[]=array("text"=>$row["Menu_Name"]);
    }
 }  
 $value1["subMenu"] = $subMenu;
 $menuData[] = $value1;
 }
 $menuDataJSON = json_encode($menuData);
 echo $menuDataJSON;
```

now i attach the full code of submenu.php page.

Comment: What error are you getting in the above code ? And what is the content of session variable in "menu.php" page ?

Comment: VM374:2 Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token < in JSON at position 2
    at JSON.parse (<anonymous>)
    at Object.success (menu.php:20)
    at i (jquery.min.js:2)
    at Object.fireWith [as resolveWith] (jquery.min.js:2)
    at A (jquery.min.js:4)
    at XMLHttpRequest.<anonymous> (jquery.min.js:4)

Comment: you could directly call the session variably with `submenu.php` .Why pass with ajax?

Comment: You can directly assign $session variable in rollid variable

Comment: you missed to `echo`  it  `var rollid = '<?php echo  json_encode($session); ?>';`

Comment: $session is array or single data ?

Comment: content of session variable in menu page is coming form login.php page. That can have value 1,2,3 depend on user login. like if admin login its value is 1.

Comment: use like this : var rollid = '<?php echo $session['roll_id']; ?>';

Comment: @prasad how i pass login page session variable in submenu.php page??

Comment: No need pass.And its not a secured one.simple same like `menu.php`  header. `<?php 
session_start();
$session = $_SESSION['roll_id'];
?> ` add with `submenu.php` file .you getting session varible

Comment: @KetanSolanki i already use this var rollid = '<?php echo $session['roll_id']; ?>' but it is also not working.

Comment: If it's `not array` `no need` `json_enocde` . just try this `var rollid = '<?php echo $session; ?>';`

Comment: @prasad i am not getting by passing it into submenu.php page. from the ajax call i am going to submenu.php page so i want to send session variable from this page only.

Comment: @JYoThI this one is also tried. without json encode.

Comment: please take a look on my below answer . overcome those issues . i mentioned below  @AnjanaChoudhary

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try like this may its helpful for you

```
<?php 
session_start();
$session = $_SESSION['roll_id'];
?>
<html>
<head>
<link href="menu_style.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script 
src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js">
</script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){

var rollid = "<?php echo $session; ?>"; //change here
alert(rollid)
$.ajax
({
    type:'post',
    url:'submenu.php',
    data:{roll_id:rollid}, // change alse here
    /*success: function (data) {
            alert(data); 
        }*/
```

Comment: menu.php:8 Uncaught SyntaxError: Invalid or unexpected token

Comment: `error` seems your `session variable` is `empty` @AnjanaChoudhary

Comment: no when i print_r then value is stored is session variable. it is not empty.

Comment: make sure your session variable is not empty so you need to check what value is stored in roll_id variable,So try to alert roll_id variable. I have updated my answer

Comment: how to check what value is stored on data roll id variable.

Comment: Please see my answer, where i have made this. You can check that with alert() or console.log(') @AnjanaChoudhary]

Comment: VM564:1 Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token < in JSON at position 0
    at JSON.parse (<anonymous>)
    at Object.success (menu.php:18)
    at i (jquery.min.js:2)
    at Object.fireWith [as resolveWith] (jquery.min.js:2)
    at A (jquery.min.js:4)
    at XMLHttpRequest.<anonymous> (jquery.min.js:4)

Comment: this is the error and one unexpected token on line 8 menu.php

Comment: i think data in not passing properly to submenu.php page. so there is error in getting response.

Comment: why you have commented success function of ajax make it uncomment

Comment: @this succes function is i write only for checking data. so i comment this. there is another success function below this where i use response.

Comment: @AnjanaChoudhary your ajax request is sent properly or not ?

Comment: @MayankVadiya  dats the i saying from beginning data variable is not passing properly on submenu.php. so error in response function.

Comment: You want pass variable `$menuData` in ajax response ? @AnjanaChoudhary

Comment: yes, when i done it statically means not taking the rollid value from session and in query put rollid=1, then response is getting successfully.

Comment: but when i using session variable to set roll id for getting dynamic menus, it is giving error.

Comment: @AnjanaChoudhary then you need to check which values are coming from ajax request and place that values in query and run in MySql directly means `print_r($_POST)` in submenu.php

Comment: @MayankVadiya i tried print_r($_POST) but it is not going on submenu.php page, means in console there is no output.

Answer (score 0):

**1st :** You `missed` to `echo` the variable .

**2nd :**  if it's not a `array` no need `json_encode`

**3rd :** Before `header` function you will not `echo` any `browser` out put like `html` or `echoing` something will cause `Warning: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent` so take care about that .

**4th :** Try to put `exit();` function after `header` function

```
  header(....);
  exit();
```

**Js :**

```
var rollid = '<?php echo $session; ?>';
```

Answer (score 0):

You echoed the `<h2 ...` on successful login and then used the `header` function to redirect. This will cause a warning `Warning: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by” and redirection might not work.

As for AJAX, you need to echo the roll_id like this:

```
var rollid = '<?php echo json_encode($session); ?>';
```

I woudl also like to point out that since rollid is a single value, you dont really need to json_encode it.

Comment: Did you add echo to that statement like `var rollid = '<?php echo ($session); ?>';`? Also, WHAT is not working for you? Is this value not available on the submenu.php? You could just use the `$session = $_SESSION['roll_id'];` in the submenu.php to get its value too.

Comment: var rollid = '<?php echo ($session); ?>'; this is done by me. when i print_r($session) it also giving correct value. but i think this value is not going on data "rollid".

Comment: Ok I think I got it. On submenu.php, change `$roll_id = $_POST['rollid'];` to `$roll_id = $_POST['roll_id'];` because you are sending `roll_id` variable and not `rollid`

Comment: this is done. i correct my this mistake already, but still some error.

Answer (score 0):

just `start_session()` at top of page and try like this

```
var rollid = "<?php echo $_SESSION['roll_id']; ?>";
```

Comment: so just print_r($_SESSION); first and check if any value store in session

Comment: also in login.php file have u use session_start(); at top of file

Comment: session_start() is also there in login page.